# Output in console log does not match when expanded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am setting an object and when I print the object I am seeing the correct value in the unexpanded log but when I expand it I see a different value. Not sure why it is acting up.

[image]

```
    const bidA = this.userBid;
    const bidB = this.updatedProject.leadingBid;
    bidA.currentBidAmt = 495;
    bidA.minAmt = 200;
    bidA.type = 'AUTO';
    console.log('Bid A: ', bidA);
```

Comment: Click on the pale-blue "i".

Comment: @cartant It says the value has been evaluated just now. So it is being updated somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of creating the log entry, your object had a `currentBidAmt` of `495`.
In the meantime the value has been updated to `475` by the application.

Chrome does not copy the full object when logging it but only creates a string representation of it for (some of) the values it sees at that time. Nevertheless it keeps a reference to the live object which is evaluated when expanding the log entry. That's why you see its current values.

A suggested work around to get the current value is to use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). This will evaluate the value of what you want to log at the time of logging. The output will be a string-representation of the Object.